# Port an existing Quickly app from 12.04 to 12.10?

Tags: upgrade, application-development, quickly

I've developed an app using Quickly on a 12.04 system.  In preparation for the 12.10 release, I'd like to have launchpad build a version for Quantal so that it can be used and tested by people from my ppa.  I'm not willing to upgrade my system yet (I depend on it for work), how can I do this from 12.04 and my current quickly project?  I have a virtualbox with 12.10 installed for testing, but I don't want to copy over the quickly project if I don't have to.

Ideally, an answer should work with the `quickly submitubuntu` command so that it is packaged for installation in the `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com` directory.

Edit: I posted one solution below, but it makes the numbering go out of sync. If anyone has a better idea, please post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds/GettingStarted) site could help you with the distribution packaging of your quickly app on launchpad. I had the same problem before, and now my app also runs on Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out... This should work for building binaries for any arbitrary release.  Just do the following:

```
quickly configure target-distribution quantal
quickly submitubuntu
```

You should be able to just sequentially reconfigure for each distribution. Unfortunately this puts the release numbering out of order. I don't know how to synchronize release numbering over multiple target-distributions.